# Laravel - Attempting auth

Tags: laravel, authentication

I'm trying to manually auth my user like this :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\User;
use Auth;
use Log;
use Hash;

class UsersController extends Controller
{
    public function authenticate(Request $request){
        $email = $request->input('email');
        $password = $request->input('password');


        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {

            // Authentication passed...
            return response()->json(User::find($email));
        }

        return response()->json(null);
    }
}
```

I verify my request data, my database data, all is ok. I've also done a Hash::check with my user password and my request password, all is ok.

But the attempt always returning false.

Thanks !

Comment: i think you missed to include response facades     use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;

Comment: can you add exit in your code like this `dd(Auth::attempt())` with arguments and see it its returning true or false.

Comment: I made a Hash::check() with the password in my database and the password of my form and the result was true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found it.

This was because I was attending a result but

```
return response()->json(User::find($email));
```

didn't find a user. So I change it for the following

```
return response()->json(User::where('email', $email)->first());
```

Thanks !